# python pandas flag if more than one unique row per value in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flags

In the following DataFrame, I have three columns:

```
   Code      |   Category  |    Count
     X               A          89734
     X               A          239487
     Y               B          298787
     Z               B          87980
     W               C          098454
```

I need to add a column, that if a category has more than one unique code (like B in the example above), it gets a flag denoting it as a test.

So the output I am looking for is this:

```
   Code      |   Category  |    Count    | Test_Flag
     X               A          89734       
     X               A          239487
     Y               B          298787         T
     Z               B          87980          T
     W               C          098454
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also opt for [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for filling the values.

```
df['Test_flag'] = np.where(df.groupby('Category').Code.transform('nunique') > 1, 'T', '')


>>> df
  Category Code   Count Test_flag
0        A    X   89734          
1        A    X  239487          
2        B    Y  298787         T
3        B    Z   87980         T
4        C    W   98454
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filtration](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) with [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) for finding `index values` and then create new columns with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.groupby('Category').Code.filter(lambda x: x.nunique() > 1))
2    Y
3    Z
Name: Code, dtype: object

idx = df.groupby('Category').Code.filter(lambda x: x.nunique() > 1).index
print (idx)
Int64Index([2, 3], dtype='int64')

df.loc[idx, 'Test_Flag'] = 'T'
#if necessary, replace NaN to empty string
#df.Test_Flag = df.Test_Flag.fillna('')

print (df)
  Code Category   Count Test_Flag
0    X        A   89734       NaN
1    X        A  239487       NaN
2    Y        B  298787         T
3    Z        B   87980         T
4    W        C   98454       NaN
```

Another solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for boolean mask used in `loc`:

```
print (df.groupby('Category').Code.transform('nunique'))
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    1
Name: Code, dtype: int64

mask = df.groupby('Category').Code.transform('nunique') > 1
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: Code, dtype: bool

df.loc[mask, 'Test_Flag'] = 'T'
#if necessary, replace NaN to empty string
#df.Test_Flag = df.Test_Flag.fillna('')

print (df)
  Code Category   Count Test_Flag
0    X        A   89734       NaN
1    X        A  239487       NaN
2    Y        B  298787         T
3    Z        B   87980         T
4    W        C   98454       NaN
```