# python pandas apply if statement and groupby only for one category

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, group-by

Piggy backing of this question [python pandas flag if more than one unique row per value in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473831/python-pandas-flag-if-more-than-one-unique-row-per-value-in-column)

I want to apply the following rule only to rows with Type X.

```
df['Test_flag'] = np.where(df.groupby('Category').Code.transform('nunique') > 1, 'T', '')
```

Dataframe df:

```
    Code      |  Type  | Category  |    Count
    code1          Y        A          89734
    code1          Y        A          239487
    code2          Z        B          298787
    code3          Z        B          87980
    code4          Y        C          098454
    code5          X        D          298787
    code6          X        D          87980
```

Expected result:

```
    Code      |  Type  | Category  |    Count  | Test Flag
    code1          Y        A          89734
    code1          Y        A          239487
    code2          Z        B          298787
    code3          Z        B          87980
    code4          Y        C          098454
    code5          X        D          298787       T
    code6          X        D          87980        T
```

Explanation:

1. Category A has the same codes and is not Type X -> so no flag T
2. Category B has different codes, but is not Type X -> so no flag T
3. Category C has only one code and is not Type X -> so no flag T
4. Category D has different codes and is Type X **-> FLAG T**

I tried this

```
  df['Test_flag'] = np.where((df['Type'] == 'X') &df.groupby('Category').Code.transform('nunique') > 1, 'T', '')
```

and I get the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,2199) (7620,)
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['Type'] == 'X', 'Test_flag'] = ...` ?

Comment: correct - one category "D", but two different codes; while category A has the same codes and category B has different codes, but is not type X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing parentheses in the logical-and which will cause the order of operations in the condition to be parsed incorrectly. Besides that, your logic looks like it should work.

```
df['Test_flag'] = (np.where((df.Type == 'X') &
                            (df.groupby('Category').Code.transform('nunique') > 1), 
                            'T', ''))
```

**Minimal Demo**

```
>>> df 
  Category   Code  Count Type
0        A  code1      1    Y
1        A  code1      2    Y
2        B  code2      3    Z
3        B  code3      4    Z
4        C  code4      5    Y
5        D  code5      4    X
6        D  code6      2    X

>>> df['Test_flag'] = (np.where((df.Type == 'X') &
                                (df.groupby('Category').Code.transform('nunique') > 1), 
                                'T', ''))

>>> df
  Category   Code  Count Type Test_flag
0        A  code1      1    Y          
1        A  code1      2    Y          
2        B  code2      3    Z          
3        B  code3      4    Z          
4        C  code4      5    Y          
5        D  code5      4    X         T
6        D  code6      2    X         T
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be reading this wrong, but I think this is a little more intuitive (to me at least) and doesn't require numpy:

```
df['Test Flag'] = ''
df['Test Flag'][(~df['Code'].duplicated()) & (df['Type'] == 'X')] = 'T'
```

Result:

```
    Code Type Category   Count Test Flag
0  code1    Y        A   89734          
1  code1    Y        A  239487          
2  code2    Z        B  298787          
3  code3    Z        B   87980          
4  code4    Y        C  098454          
5  code5    X        D  298787         T
6  code6    X        D   87980         T
```